# How can I use declaration file inside npm package using typescript?

Tags: typescript, npm, type-declaration

I have a package in my node_modules folder which has typings.d.ts and package.json
In package.json I set "types": "typings.d.ts"

typings.d.ts

```
export { T1, T2, T3} from '@somepackage';

interface Window {
    additionalProp: any;
}

export declare var window: Window;
```

And when I'm using this declaration file in some service:

```
import { window } from '../typings';


export class SomeService {
    someMethod(): void {
        if (window && window.additionalProp) {
           someLogic();
        }
    }
}
```

I have no compilation errors
But when I build a project, I get next errors:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../typings'
```

I've read about declare module, triple dash imports, etc. nothing really helped :(

Comment: It would help us help you to know which npm module you'e trying to use.

Comment: It's my own npm package

Comment: Do you mean it's a private package? Because otherwise it doesn't really matter whether it's yours or someone else's.

Comment: Yes, it's a private package

Answer (score 0):

You don't use a relative path with modules in `node_modules`. You'd import those types by using

```
import { window } from "the-package-name/typings";
```

...where `the-package-name` is the name of the package in `node_modules` that contains `typings.d.ts`.

Comment: Still got the same error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@package/directory/typings'